# Octave: "load: failed to load matrix constant"

Tags: image, matlab, save, octave

I would like to save and load a set of images in Octave / Matlab. The general instructions given [in the FAQ](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_process_a_sequence_of_files.3F) do not seem to work with saving and loading (octave 3.2.4, Ubuntu 12.04).

Namely, using [bg_header_mwlogo_notag.jpg](http://www.mathworks.com/includes_content/nextgen/images/bg_header_mwlogo_notag.jpg)

```
images = cell(1, 1);
for i=1
    images{i} = imread('/tmp/bg_header_mwlogo_notag.jpg');
end
save images;
load images;
```

gives:

```
error: load: failed to load matrix constant
error: load: trouble reading ascii file `'
error: load: reading file 
error: load: cell array element had unexpected name
error: load: failed to load cell element
error: load: trouble reading ascii file `images'
error: load: reading file images
```

How can I save and load several images to and from one file?

Comment: I replicated your test and it does not give me any problem. Same setup as yours.

Comment: @LucaGeretti: Thanks, I have changed the code to something that should consistently give the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem loading the ASCII representation of the matrix from file. If you rather issue

```
images{i} = double(imread('/tmp/bg_header_mwlogo_notag.jpg'));
```

it actually stores the numeric values instead, which is perfectly fine for Matlab. You can easily check that the two representations are equal. On the other hand, loading such numeric version of the matrix from file succeeds.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. Storing as a double seems to slow down saving and loading, but this fixes the error message.